# Google Map Autocomplete types for airports

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My autocomplete url i'm using in my curl is this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=JFK&key=<<<KEY>>>&types=geocode&fields=airport,photos,icon,geometry
```

and returns this

```
{"predictions":[{"description":"JFK - Terminal 7, Jamaica, NY, USA","id":"f67e5c44e0c45e7f4a49ed96bd737bc70d3a1e42","matched_substrings":[{"length":3,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJOV8Ah_dmwokRXifsiI5gs9E","reference":"ChIJOV8Ah_dmwokRXifsiI5gs9E","structured_formatting":{"main_text":"JFK - Terminal 7","main_text_matched_substrings":[{"length":3,"offset":0}],"secondary_text":"Jamaica, NY, USA"},"terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"JFK - Terminal 7"},{"offset":18,"value":"Jamaica"},{"offset":27,"value":"NY"},{"offset":31,"value":"USA"}],"types":["premise","geocode"]},{"description":"Terminal 5, Jamaica, NY, USA","id":"27fb6511d4bfacef4563c3cc25c3b1aed9098c56","matched_substrings":[{"length":10,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJG45Wb19mwokRNXsvcPYOEzo","reference":"ChIJG45Wb19mwokRNXsvcPYOEzo","structured_formatting":{"main_text":"Terminal 5","main_text_matched_substrings":[{"length":10,"offset":0}],"secondary_text":"Jamaica, NY, USA"},"terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"Terminal 5"},{"offset":12,"value":"Jamaica"},{"offset":21,"value":"NY"},{"offset":25,"value":"USA"}],"types":["premise","geocode"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

i'm trying to get the name of the airport 1st, followed by any other matches. But i seem to sometimes get airport, and sometimes i get just the terminals.

been going thru the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) and [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) but can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to get it to work like [mozio](https://mozio.com) where if you type in JFK, JFK airport comes up 1st, then the airports. What type / field am i missing in my URL? Thanks

Comment: `&types=geocode&fields=airport&fields=photos` read that again...

Comment: 1) "airport" is not a valid type 2) "fields" is not supported by the Autocomplete 3) You are referring to the wrong documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `establishment` type parameter which is supported by place autocomplete web service.

When I execute the following request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=JFK&types=establishment&key=MY_API_KEY`

The first prediction is

JFK Airport (JFK), Queens, NY, USA (place ID ChIJR0lA1VBmwokR8BGfSBOyT-w)

You can see the place in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJR0lA1VBmwokR8BGfSBOyT-w

I hope this helps!

Comment: So i guess if i needed to have 2 types (establishment & geocode) i will have to do 2 queries and merge the arrays?